# Checkbox Filtering when using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to html and javascript so this may be a very simple question. I'm trying to create a tool that allows a user to see a list of items and click on each one for more information, but also have criteria on the side that cuts the list down for specific tasks. I found an example that is almost exactly what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't use buttons in the main list. This is the example I was using as a template http://jsfiddle.net/n3EmN/3/ 
Also, what I understand the string part of the javascript, but how much of that can I remove without affecting the code? Can I completely have it not show what is being removed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <pre id=result> </pre>  
  <style> 
    body {
       background: #c4c4c4
     }
  </style>

  <style>
    button.accordion {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 340px;
      border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
      position: relative;
      top: -40px;
      left: 15px;
   }

   button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
      background-color: white;
   }

   button.accordion:after {
     content: '\002B';
     color: #777;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 5px;
   }

   button.accordion.active:after {
     content: "\2212";
   }

   div.panel {
     padding: 0 16px;
     cursor: default;
     background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.65);
     text-align: right;
     font-size: 20px;
     max-height: 0;
     width: 308px;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
     position: relative;
     top: -40px;
     left: 15px;
   }

 </style>

 <style>
   button.accordian {
     background-color: #eee;
     color: #444;
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 15px;
     width: 750px;
     text-align: left;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-weight: bold; 
     border: none;
     -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
        -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
             transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
     position: relative;
     top: -245px;
     left: 500px;
     z-index: 2;
  }
  button.accordian.active, button.accordian:hover {
     background-color: white;
  }

  button.accordian:after {
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     float: right;
     margin-left: 5px;
  }

div.pane {
       padding: 0 16px;
   cursor: default;
   background-color: white;
   border: 1px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 14px;
   max-height: 0;
   width: 716px;
   overflow: hidden;
   transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
       position: relative;
   top: -245px;
   left: 500px;
   z-index: 1;
}

 </style>

 <style> 
.contact {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #444;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: relative;
    top: -220px;
    left: 15px;
}
 </style>

<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/loadcontent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/filter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/loaddatafromxm1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/prefixfree-1.0.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
<script src="js/loadXMLDoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/navisearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/dropdownsearch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 <div class="pic" id="pic">
<p style="text-align: center;">
   <img src="https://thisdayinwaterhistory.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/0518-dow-logo.jpg" style="width: 50%;"></img>
</p>
 </div> 


 <div class="contact">
<p>
  Contact: Someone
</p>
<p>
  Email: person@email.com
</p>
<p>
  Phone: (###)###-####
</p>
 </div>   

 <button class="accordion"><b>Structure Type</b></button>
 <div class="panel">
    <li>
      <a title="(Storage tank)">
    <b>Storage tank</b>
        <input name="sturcture" type="checkbox" value="storage" id="storage"></input>
      </a>
    </li>
<li>
  <a title="(Furnace)">
    <b>Furnace</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="furnace" id="furnace"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Reactor/Agitator)">
    <b>Reactor/Agitator</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="reactor" id="reactor"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Steam Drum)">
    <b>Steam Drum</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="steam" id="steam"></input>
  </a>
    </li>
<li>
  <a title="(Vertical/Horizontal Drum)">
    <b>Vertical/Horizontal Drum</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="drum" id="drum"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Jacketed Vessel)">
    <b>Jacketed Vessel</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="vessel" id="vessel"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Tower)">
        <b>Tower</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="tower" id="tower"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Building Roof)">
    <b>Building Roof</b>
    <input name="structure" type="checkbox" value="roof" id="roof"></input>
  </a>
</li>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion"><b>Pipes</b></button>
 <div class="panel">
    <li>
  <a title="(Large Diameter)">
    <b>Greater than 12 inch diameter </b>
    <input name="pipe" type="checkbox" value="large" id="large"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Small Diameter)">
    <b>Less than 12 inch diameter </b>
    <input name="pipe" type="checkbox" value="small" id="small"></input>
  </a>
</li>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion"><b>Job Scope or Task</b></button>
 <div class="panel">
<li class="">
  <a title="(Internal Inspection)">
    <b>Internal Inspection</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="internal" id="internal"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(External Inspection)">
    <b>External Inspection</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="external" id="external"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Underwater Inspection)">
    <b>Underwater Inspection</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="underwater" id="underwater"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Corrosion Mapping)">
    <b>Corrosion Mapping</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="corrosion" id="corrosion"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Thickness Testing)">
    <b>UT Thickness Testing</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="thickness" id="thickness"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Thermography)">
    <b>Thermography</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="thermography" id="thermography"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Cleaning)">
    <b>Cleaning</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="cleaning" id="cleaning"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="">
  <a title="(Flare Lighting)">
    <b>Flare Lighting</b>
    <input name="scope" type="checkbox" value="flare" id="flare"></input>
  </a>
</li>  
 </div>

 <button class="accordion"><b>Job and Equipment Conditions</b></button>
 <div class="panel">
<li>
  <a title="(Dry/Empty)">
    <b>Dry and/or Empty</b>
    <input name="conditions" type="checkbox" value="dry" id="dry"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Contains Liquid)">
    <b>Contains liquid</b>
    <input name="conditions" type="checkbox" value="wet" id="wet"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Metallic)">
    <b>Ferrous Material</b>
    <input name="conditions" type="checkbox" value="ferrous" id="ferrous"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Non-Metallic)">
    <b>Non-ferrous Material</b>
    <input name="conditions" type="checkbox" value="non-ferrous" id="non-ferrous"></input>
  </a>
</li>
 </div>

 <button class="accordion"><b>Distance of Work from Entry</b></button>
 <div class="panel">
<li>
  <a title="(Close To Entry)">
    <b>Within 10 feet</b>
    <input name="distance" type="checkbox" value="short" id="short"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Medium Distance From entry)">
    <b>Between 10 and 25 feet</b>
    <input name="distance" type="checkbox" value="medium" id="medium"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Somewhat Far From Entry)">
    <b>Between 25 and 50 feet</b>
    <input name="distance" type="checkbox" value="far" id="far"></input>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a title="(Very Far From Entry)">
    <b>Greater than 50 feet</b>
    <input name="distance" type="checkbox" value="veryfar" id="veryfar"></input>
  </a>
</li>
 </div>

 <button class="accordian" data-id="Nano Crawler" data-category="storage steam drum vessel tower large small internal dry wet ferrous close medium far"><b> Nano Crawler </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="Nano Crawler">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://www.inuktun-europe.com/crawler-vehicles/nanomag/nanomag09_front.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-id="HD & Micromag" data-category="storage furnace reactor steam drum vessel tower large small internal corrosion thickness dry wet ferrous close medium far"><b> HD & Micromag </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="Micromag">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://www.inuktun-europe.com/crawler-vehicles/micromag/micromag-magnetic-vertical-crawler-vehicle-2.png" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian"  data-id="Versatrax 100" data-category="storage large small internal dry wet ferrous non-ferrous close medium far"><b> Versatrax 100 </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="Versatrax 100">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://img.nauticexpo.com/images_ne/photo-g/39946-333259.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-id="Versatrax 50" data-category="storage large small internal dry wet ferrous non-ferrous close medium far"><b> Versatrax 50 </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="Versatrax 50">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54da86e7e4b0d304c267efaf/t/58e28bad1b631bf0ffe965ca/1491241965875/Versatrax+50%E2%84%A2" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-category="storage external cleaning flare dry wet close medium far veryfar"><b> 510 Packbot </b></button>
 <div class="pane" data-id="510 Packbot">
     <li>
     <a title="510 Packbot">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://endeavorrobotics.com/media/images/products/510-main.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-id="Flyability Elios" data-category="storage furnace reactor steam drum vessel tower roof large internal external thermography dry ferrous non-ferrous close medium far veryfar"><b> Flyability Elios </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="Elios">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://www.unmannedsystemstechnology.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Flyability-Elios-Collision-Tolerant-UAV.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-id="SeaBotix ROV" data-category="underwater wet close medium far"><b> SeaBotix ROV </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="SeaBotix ROV">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://images.marinetechnologynews.com/images/maritime/w800h500/seabotix-vlbv-41253.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>
 <button class="accordian" data-id="VideoRay Sub" data-category="underwater wet close medium far"><b> VideoRay Sub </b></button>
 <div class="pane">
     <li>
     <a title="VideoRay Sub">
       <p style="text-align: center;">
         <img src="http://www.hydrographic-catalogue.com/photos/big/336-3-video-ray-pro4-rov.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></img>
       </p>
     </a>
     </li>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>

<script>
     var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordian");
     var i;

     for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
 </script>

 <script data-type="javascript">
     var byStructure = [], bySize = [], byScope = [], byCondition = [], byDistance = [];

    $("input[name=structure]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byStructure.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byStructure, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input[name=pipe]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) bySize.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(bySize, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input[name=scope]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byScope.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byScope, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });
    $("input[name=conditions]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byCondition.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byCondition, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });
    $("input[name=distance]").on( "change", function() {
        if (this.checked) byDistance.push("[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
        else removeA(byDistance, "[data-category~='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']");
    });

    $("input").on( "change", function() {
        var str = "Include items \n";
        var selector = '', cselector = '', nselector = '';

        var $lis = $('.accordian > button'),
            $checked = $('input:checked');  

        if ($checked.length) {  

            if (byStructure.length) {       
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byStructure.join(',') + ")\n";              
                    $($('input[name=structure]:checked')).each(function(index, byStructure){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byStructure.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byStructure.id + "']";   
                        }                
                    });                 
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byStructure.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=structure]:checked')).each(function(index, byStructure){
                        selector += "[data-category~='" + byStructure.id + "']";
                    });
                }                           
            }

            if (byPipe.length) {                        
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byPipe.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                    
                    $($('input[name=pipe]:checked')).each(function(index, bySize){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + bySize.id + "']";                     
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + bySize.id + "']";    
                        }                
                    });                 
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  bySize.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                    $($('input[name=pipe]:checked')).each(function(index, bySize){
                        if(cselector === '') {
                            cselector += "[data-category~='" + bySize.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            cselector += ",[data-category~='" + bySize.id + "']";   
                        }                   
                    });
                }           
            }

            if (byScope.length) {           
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byScope.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=scope]:checked')).each(function(index, byScope){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byScope.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byScope.id + "']";   
                        }                
                    });             
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byScope.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=scope]:checked')).each(function(index, byScope){
                        if(nselector === '') {
                            nselector += "[data-category~='" + byScope.id + "']";                   
                        } else {
                            nselector += ",[data-category~='" + byScope.id + "']";  
                        }   
                    });
                }            
            }

            if (byCondition.length) {           
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byCondition.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=condition]:checked')).each(function(index, byCondition){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byCondition.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byCondition.id + "']";   
                        }                
                    });             
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byCondition.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=condition]:checked')).each(function(index, byCondition){
                        if(nselector === '') {
                            nselector += "[data-category~='" + byCondition.id + "']";                   
                        } else {
                            nselector += ",[data-category~='" + byCondition.id + "']";  
                        }   
                    });
                }            
            }

            if (byDistance.length) {            
                if (str == "Include items \n") {
                    str += "    " + "with (" +  byScope.join(' OR ') + ")\n";               
                    $($('input[name=distance]:checked')).each(function(index, byDistance){
                        if(selector === '') {
                            selector += "[data-category~='" + byDistance.id + "']";                     
                        } else {
                            selector += ",[data-category~='" + byDistance.id + "']";    
                        }                
                    });             
                } else {
                    str += "    AND " + "with (" +  byDistance.join(' OR ') + ")\n";                
                    $($('input[name=distance]:checked')).each(function(index, byDistance){
                        if(nselector === '') {
                            nselector += "[data-category~='" + byDistance.id + "']";                    
                        } else {
                            nselector += ",[data-category~='" + byDistance.id + "']";   
                        }   
                    });
                }            
            }
        $lis.hide(); 
        console.log(selector);
        console.log(cselector);
        console.log(nselector);

        if (cselector === '' && nselector === '') {         
            $('.accordian > button').filter(selector).show();
        } else if (cselector === '') {
            $('.accordian > button').filter(selector).filter(nselector).show();
        } else if (nselector === '') {
            $('.accordian > button').filter(selector).filter(cselector).show();
        } else {
            $('.accordian > button').filter(selector).filter(cselector).filter(nselector).show();
        }

        } else {
            $lis.show();
        }   

        $("#result").html(str); 

    });

    function removeA(arr) {
        var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
        while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
            what = a[--L];
            while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                arr.splice(ax, 1);
            }
        }
        return arr;
        }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well currently it doesn't work with how I have it. I'm wondering how to filter down my list based on which checkboxes I have checked off? For example, if I checked an underwater inspection all the robots except submarines would disappear

Comment: Please be specific so we can understand how to begin to help you. What does *doesn't work* mean? Do you get an error in your developer's console (press F12 in your browser and click to the tab called "console", then run the code)? What behavior is or isn't happening?

Comment: There are no errors that I come across. When I click any of the checkboxes, none of the items in the list disappear